# CSOM - Check if Content Type already exists in list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, content-type

I'm migrating a custom list from SharePoint 2010 on-premises to SharePoint Online. The source list has content types enabled and two custom content types associated.
When migrating the list, i need to compare the associated content types collections, and add to the destination list all missing content types from the source list.

Here's my code:

```
var srcCTs = srcList.ContentTypes;
var destCTs = destList.ContentTypes;
var missingCTs = srcList.ContentTypes.Where(ct => !(destList.ContentTypes.Select(dct => dct.<UniqueKey>).Contains(ct.<UniqueKey>)));
```

where UniqueKey should be a property with unique values.
I cannot use properties "Id", "StringId" or "Name" because its values are not unique, so I think I must change the code (or at least the third row)...

How do I check if content type already exists in the destination list?

**EDIT:**
I need to compare both Content Type Collections (srcCTs and destCTs) and extract the difference between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution using the Parent Content Type (as any association to the list creates a new child instance of the content type).

```
var missingCTs = srcList.ContentTypes.Where(ct => !(destList.ContentTypes.Select(dct => dct.Parent.StringId).Contains(ct.Parent.StringId))).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

This will return all the content types into a list

```
var listContentType = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle('listTitle').ContentTypes
```

A full example

```
string siteURL = "http://your_site/";
ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteURL);
ContentTypeCollection contentTypeColl = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("listTitle").ContentTypes;
clientContext.Load(contentTypeColl);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

//Display the Content Type name
foreach (ContentType ct in contentTypeColl)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ct.Name);
}
```

Hope be helpful

Comment: Thank you for your response, but it's not what I'm looking for. I need to compare two Content Type Collections (coll A and coll B) and extract the difference between them.